# Select a part of a text file BATCH

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm working with BATCH and I have an Apache configuration file like this:

```
< IfModule mpm_prefork_module >
    StartServers 5
    MinSpareServers 5
    MaxSpareServers 10
    MaxRequestWorkers 250
    MaxConnectionsPerChild 0
< / IfModule >


< IfModule mpm_worker_module >
    StartServers 3
    MinSpareThreads 75
    MaxSpareThreads 250
    ThreadsPerChild 25
    MaxRequestWorkers 400
    MaxConnectionsPerChild 0
< / IfModule >
```

**My question is if there is any way you can select only a piece of this file**, ie "read" only the text between < IfModule mpm_worker_module > and < / IfModule > so that the output is only:

```
< IfModule mpm_worker_module >
    StartServers 3
    MinSpareThreads 75
    MaxSpareThreads 250
    ThreadsPerChild 25
    MaxRequestWorkers 400
    MaxConnectionsPerChild 0
< / IfModule >
```

Thank you! : D

Comment: So you want only the second one?Or the last one?Are there any other modules? How you can say which one you need?

Comment: The answer is: ***Yes.*** There are actually numerous ways, but if you do not show what you have tried and describe where you are stuck, this kind of "do my work for me" question is off-topic on SO...

Comment: What do you want to do with the lines inside your block? Store them in variables, export them into a different file or execute them somehow?

Comment: Just get the value and save it to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't know what you want to do with the lines inside between `< IfModule mpm_worker_module >` and `< / IfModule >`, I will simply echo them out. However, it's not a big deal to process them in any other way. You still have to set `inFile` to the actual file you want to parse.

```
@echo OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set inFile=input.txt
set startTokenFound=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%l in (%inFile%) DO (
    set line=%%l
    if "%%l"=="< / IfModule >" set startTokenFound=0
    if !startTokenFound!==1 echo %%l
    if "%%l"=="< IfModule mpm_worker_module >" set startTokenFound=1
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much , that's just what I needed.
The reason is that I started working with batch not long ago, and it does not really occurred to me how to do so. The truth is that I need to get the value in between the IfModule's because, depending on how Apache is working , I have to acquire a value or another, but I was getting all the possible values. It was just that.